# Colouring a sequence

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Define a 2 coloring of $\left \{ \left. 0,1 \right \}^* \right.$ to be a function $\chi:\left \{ \left. 0,1 \right \}^* \right. \rightarrow \left \{ \left. red,blue \right \} \right. $ 
e.g. if $\chi(1101)=red$, we say that 1101 is red in the coloring of $\chi$.

Prove: For every 2 coloring $\chi$ of $\left \{ \left. 0,1 \right \}^* \right.$ and every (infinite) binary sequence $S \in \left \{ \left. 0,1 \right \}^\infty \right.$

There is a sequence:

$$w_{0},w_{1},w_{2},...$$

of strings $w_{n} \in \left \{ \left. 0,1 \right \}^* \right.$ such that:

i) $S= w_{0}w_{1}w_{2}...$ and

ii)  $w_{1},w_{2},...$ are all the same color. (The string $w_{0}$ may not be this color).

---

I have tried making arguments that you can split any sequence and define each 'half' as the colorings. This then fails for an infinite sequence. I am not sure how to 'prove' such a result. I'm not sure if you can split it into cases where the infinite sequence is repeating or non-repeating etc.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Shouldn't $w_1w_2$, $w_2w_3$, $w_1w_2w_3$, $w_3w_4$, $w_2w_3w_4$, $w_1w_2w_3w_4$, $w_4w_5$, etc. also be the same color as $w_2$, $w_2$, $w_3$, etc.?

Comment: Isn't this a direct consequence of [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem)?

Comment: @bof: No, why? $\Chi$ is any colouring. My idea will be to have an infinite graphs with vertices $u_i\ldots u_j$ where $S=u_0u_1\ldots$ and each $u_i\in\{0,1\}$. $u_i\ldots u_j$ would be connected to $u_{j+1}\ldots u_k$ by a directed edge colored "c" if $\Chi(u_i\ldots u_j)=\Chi(u_{j+1}\ldots u_k)=c$. Probably some kind of Ramsey-like argument could be applied on that.

Comment: @Faustus My idea would be to consider a graph with vertices $0,1,2,3,\dots$; for $i\lt j$, vertices $i$ and $j$ would be joined by an edge of color $c$ if $\chi(u_{i+1}u_{i+2}\dots u_j)=c$. By Ramsey's theorem there is an infinite sequence $i_0\lt i_1\lt i_2\lt\cdots$ such that all edges joining any two of them are the same color. Then let $w_0=u_0\dots u_{i_0}$, $w_1=u_{i_0+1}\dots u_{i_1}$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following very nice solution is not mine, apparently it is by [Philipp Czerner](https://nicze.de/philipp/), I found it on [a discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=39720388) on HN.

Let $\color{blue}{\textrm{B}} = \{i; \, \chi(S[i \dots j]) = \color{blue}{\text{blue}} \; \forall j \geq i \}$, that means $\color{blue}{\textrm{B}}$ is the set of all indexes $i$ so that all substring of $S$ starting from $i$ is blue. There are two cases:

- $\color{blue}{\textrm{B}}$ is infinite: then we have an infinite sequence $i_1 < i_2 < \dots$ of elements of $\color{blue}{\textrm{B}}$. Let $w_k = S[i_k \dots \left(i_{k+1}-1\right)]$, obviously $\chi\left(w_k\right) = \color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ for all $k \geq 1$
- $\color{blue}{\textrm{B}}$ is finite: let $k$ be the largest element of $\color{blue}{\textrm{B}}$, for any index $i > k$ there is always a substring $w = S[i \dots j]$ (i.e. substring starting from $i$) so that $\chi(w) = \color{red}{\text{red}}$